# Can I use z-scores to flag datapoints on right-skewed data?

Tags: distributions, z-score

I have a dataset that is massively right-skewed.

I want to flag datapoints that are >=3 standard deviations from the mean for further investigation.

Is this a valid way of doing things considering my data is right skewed, and not normal?

I don't need to know the proportion of data that has a z-score of >=3, I just need to flag these datapoints in a massive dataset.

Comment: "Massively right-skewed" is tantamount to saying you know you will flag an inordinately large proportion of the points.  How would that help?  What is the inherent problem with skewness?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What would you sees as a valid way to do this that differs from calculating the standard deviation, multiplying by three, and adding that value to the mean?

Comment: The dataset is transactions on a money transfer platform. So I want to flag large $ amounts and high numbers of transactions, from unknown senders. I feel that this would be a step in the right direction towards looking into strange transactions. The total dataset is >100k rows of transactions. The vast majority of the data is within a small range, but there are a few outliers skewing the data to the right. I'm wondering if the the zscore would be a good flag?

Comment: A good flag for what? It may depend on what you mean by "further investigation". If you flag say 5% of 100k  transactions as "strange", that's 5000 transactions to investigate.

Comment: Many people would just sort the values by decreasing amount and start investigating from the top down as time and budget permit.  There's likely a (much) better method that would account for other factors in the transactions, but this is about all we can say without knowing more details of your data.